# Motorola Moto G 2014 (lollipop 5.0.2): `pm set-install-location 2' does not work

Tags: updates, sd-card, installation, motorola-moto-g

I have rooted my Motorola Moto G 2014 (lollipop 5.0.2), using TWRP to load SuperSU.

I wanted to have all applications that could store some of their data on an external SD to do so automatically, when they are installed or updated (i.e. for the `MOVE TO SD` action to be automated).

After reading several guides, and answers on to questions on this forum, I thought this could be achieved by executing the following commands:

```
su
pm set-install-location 2
```

However, the behaviour after the above setting change was undesirable.

When apps that I knew had the ability to `MOVE TO SD` were installed or updated, they were still being stored on the device's memory, not on the external SD card.

Also, entries appeared for more apps than are usually displayed in the `ON SD CARD` tab, within `Apps` settings.

If the `MOVE TO SD` action was performed on these new entries, the device's behaviour became erratic. App links disappeared from the launcher, and `Unfortunately, app_name has stopped.` messages were encountered.

I just want for applications that can be moved partially to the SD card to do so automatically.